# Where do you get your CA bundles (crt's) for postfix?

Tags: ssl, postfix, centos6

Learning postfix, I've set up SSL on my server and everything is working.

Google/Gmail was saying `Untrusted TLS connection established` until I downloaded an Equifax SSL CA bundle and added it to my CA bundle. Now it says `trusted connection` whenever sending an email to Google.

So now I'm trying to do the same for Yahoo and Outlook365 connections. The connections say `Untrusted TLS connection established` whenever I send them emails.

Am I going about this the right way? by downloading CA bundles and putting them in my CA bundle? I've tried `ssl_CA_path` and just putting them in there, but that didn't work, only `smtp_tls_CAfile` seems to work.

- Centos 6.7
- postfix 3.2.2

Comment: The CA bundles that come with your distribution should be sufficient. Did you configure your postfix to not use them?

Comment: I don't remember enabling anything to use the CA bundles that come with the distribution. It was a minimal Centos installation if that makes a difference. What keywords should I be looking for to find out if I have it set? The SSL I installed was a Comodo Essential Certificate with its 3-4? certificate intermediate bundle

Comment: Oh I see, you must be referencing /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt . Yep, that did it... It worked. Issue was I pointed to the CA-bundle Comodo gave me instead of the system's. Thank you.

Comment: Well, normally buying a certificate for this kind of usage is an utter waste of money. If you got hordes of users, yes, using a well known CA might come in handy. If it's just you, it's wasted money. Anyway, you can easily get a certificate from Let's Encrypt for free, use it for exactly this kind of purpose and automate the renewal process entirely with the right tool and a cron job. Having said that, using DANE would remove the need for a paid CA entirely, though this is unlikely to ever happen. But Postfix can use it.

Comment: @MarcStürmer the question is about outgoing connections, not incoming.

Comment: This does not change the fact that also for this kind of usage a certificate from Let's Encrypt works very well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every (major) Linux distribution comes with CA certificates from all major authorities that are usually trusted.

This is the default location for CentOS:

```
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

This should be used by default, so you shouldn't need this line unless you want to trust your own CA only.

The CA files are provided by the package `ca-certificates`. If for some reason the CA bundles are not present you can install them using `yum install ca-certificates`.

Comment: Google _may become_ a special case, _if_ they extend their intermediate-CA cert beyond 2018-08 (currently 2017-12) which I expect they will _and_ continue to serve the Geotrust-bridge-to-Equifax path _and_ Postfix is using an OpenSSL that doesn't 'switch' to the direct Geotrust root which might well remain true for 1.0.1 in CentOS 6; see my answer at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66487/what-happens-when-certificates-further-up-the-chain-expires-before-mine

Comment: Can they be yum-updated safely ? I mean that won't break the local server certificate, right ?

Comment: The package only contains root certificates. The server certificate has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question from from [How to resolve server certificate not trusted in postfix on Debian?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1016248/how-to-resolve-server-certificate-not-trusted-in-postfix-on-debian)
If Lets Encrypt is involved, the answer is slightly different.

First, make sure that you are clear between smtp_* and smtpd_* parameters. Becuase you are concerned about mail going out, you should worry about the smtp_* parameters.
[What's the difference between postfix/smtp and postfix/smtpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/696936/whats-the-difference-between-postfix-smtp-and-postfix-smtpd)

This setup worked for me with a Let's Encrypt certificate. Many forums told me to reference the fullchain as the smtp_tls_CAfile, but they failed to mention that you also need the smtp_tls_CApath parameter set also. After getting it working with all four of these lines, I commented out the smtp_tls_CAfile and it worked with just the smtp_tls_CApath

```
smtp_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
smtp_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
#smtp_tls_CAfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem #optional
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
```